# PyMySQL adding 100 columns dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

Im trying to add 100 columns at runtime using below code.
i tried "https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/45526-convert-string-tuple"
but the error remains same

```
    import csv
    import pymysql.cursors

    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='',db='DWM',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    c = connection.cursor()

    str2 =""
    for i in range(0,100):
      str2 = "t"+str(i)
      print(str2)
      sql = "ALTER TABLE Check2 ADD column %s varchar(100)", eval(str2)
      c.execute(sql)
```

the error is:

```
   t0
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "check.py", line 14, in <module>
       sql = "ALTER TABLE Check2 ADD column %s varchar(100)", eval(str2)
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   NameError: name 't0' is not defined
```

Can anyone point out my mistake?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
sql = "ALTER TABLE Check2 ADD column %s varchar(100)", eval(str2)
```

with

```
sql = "ALTER TABLE Check2 ADD column {} varchar(100)".format(str2)
```

or equivalently

```
sql = f"ALTER TABLE Check2 ADD column {str2} varchar(100)"
```

Comment: try removing eval too

Comment: now error is different one : pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; chec
k the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right synta
x to use near '%s varchar(100)' at line 1")

Comment: did you replace `%s` with `{}` ?